# Оформление чисел с плавающей запятой в Python

Tags: python

Для оформления задачи мне нужно представить числа в определенном формате.
Например число

`-7.816585631337434e-12` нужно представить в виде `-7.816 * 10^12`

Для положительных чисел без отрицательной степени у "е" я использовал метод toFixed()

```
def toFixed(numObj, digits=0):
    return f"{numObj:.{digits}f}"
```

Как я могу реализовать нужный вид для числа, которое я представил выше?

Comment: Перевести в строковую переменную и дальше использовать функции для работы со строками.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот, например так:

```
f = -7.816585631337434e-12
s = str(f)
dp = s.find(".")
base = s[:dp + 4]
ep = s.find("e")
m = s[ep + 1:]
if int(m) < 0:
    m = "(" + m + ")"
print(base, "*", "10^" + m)
```

вернёт результат

> -7.816 * 10^(-12)

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

def pow_format(num, digits=3):
    ex = int(math.log10(abs(num)))

    # Если число по модулю меньше 10, то вывести без экспоненты
    if ex == 0:
        return f"{num:.{digits}f}"

    m = num / 10 ** ex

    if abs(m) < 1:
        m *= 10
        ex -= 1

    str_ex = str(ex) if ex > 0 else f"({ex})"
    return f"{m:.{digits}f} * 10^{str_ex}"

print(pow_format(0.1))  # 1.000 * 10^(-1)
print(pow_format(-7.816585631337434e-12))  # -7.817 * 10^(-12)
print(pow_format(-7.816585631337434e12))  # -7.817 * 10^12
print(pow_format(5))  # 5.000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n, e = str(number).split("e")
result = f"{float(n):.3f} * 10^{e}"
```